# Substituir última ocorrência de "a" em uma string

Tags: javascript, string, regex, replace

Como faço para substituir a última ocorrência do `a` em uma string?

```js
var myFrase = prompt(" Digite sua frase aqui: ");

for (i = 0; i < myFrase.length; i++) {
  result = myFrase.charAt(i);
  if (result == "a") {
    str = myFrase.replace(/a$/m, "@");
  }
}
document.write("<br> Substituição do a pelo @: " + str + "<br>");
```

Estou tentando fazer assim, mas só substitui o `a` pelo `@` quando o `a` está no final da palavra. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Se procuras trocar todos os `a` por `@` não precisas de ter um `for`.
Basta usar a tua `regex` na string diretamente:

```js
var myFrase = 'aaaa';
var trocada = myFrase.replace(/a$/m, "@");
console.log(trocada);
```

Se quiseres mudar todos os a e não somente o último, tira o `$` da regex.

Answer (score 2):

De fato, a regex que você usou (`/a$/`) só substitui o `a` no final justamente porque você usou o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$`, que significa "final da string". Além disso, o `for` é desnecessário pois a regex já irá percorrer toda a string procurando pelo `a`.

---

Uma solução com regex é usar `/a([^a]*)$/`. O trecho `[^a]` significa "tudo que [**não** for](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) a letra `a`" e o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` significa "zero ou mais ocorrências". E tudo isso está entre parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (já vamos entender o motivo de criá-lo).

Ou seja, a regex `/a([^a]*)$/` significa:

- a letra `a`
- seguido de zero ou mais caracteres que não são a letra `a`
- seguido do final da string

Em outras palavras, a regex pega o último `a` da string, além dos caracteres que aparecem depois, até o final da string.

Os caracteres que não são a letra `a` foram colocados entre parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), pois assim é possível usar o seu valor no `replace`. Assim eu não perco a informação do que estava depois do `a`. E como este é o primeiro par de parênteses que aparece na regex, [posso referenciá-lo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) usando a variável especial `$1`:

```js
let s = 'Uma string assim com várias letras a, mas só a última que é para substituir';

s = s.replace(/a([^a]*)$/, '@$1');
console.log(s);
// Uma string assim com várias letras a, mas só a última que é par@ substituir
```

Sendo assim, o `a` seguido de "qualquer coisa que não é `a`" é substituído por `@` seguido de `$1` (que são os mesmos caracteres que existiam depois do `a`). Com isso, somente o último `a` da string é trocado, e o restante da string permanece igual.

---

#### Solução sem regex

Também é possível uma solução sem regex, usando [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) para obter o índice do último `a` da string, e em seguida usando [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) para obter as partes da string antes e depois do `a`:

```js
let s = 'Uma string assim com várias letras a, mas só a última que é para substituir';
let antiga = 'a';
let nova = '@';

var index = s.lastIndexOf(antiga);
// se encontrou a letra
if (index >= 0) {
    s = s.substring(0, index) + nova + s.substring(index + antiga.length);
}
console.log(s);
// Uma string assim com várias letras a, mas só a última que é par@ substituir
```

O primeiro `substring` pega todo o trecho entre o início da string até a última ocorrência do `a`. O segundo `substring` pega todo o trecho logo depois desse `a`, até o final da string. E entre os dois eu coloco a nova string (no caso, `@`).

---

#### Regex versus `substring`

A solução com `substring` funciona muito bem com strings de qualquer tamanho. Exemplo:

```js
let s = 'teste 123 outro teste fim';
let antiga = 'teste';
let nova = 'abcde';

var index = s.lastIndexOf(antiga);
// se encontrou a letra
if (index >= 0) {
    s = s.substring(0, index) + nova + s.substring(index + antiga.length);
}
console.log(s);
// teste 123 outro abcde fim
```

Já se for usar regex, não adianta usar a solução acima porque a sintaxe `[^...]` ([classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)) só funciona para caracteres isolados. Para verificar se um texto inteiro é a última ocorrência, podemos usar um [*negative lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), que basicamente é uma forma da regex verificar se algo não existe à frente:

```js
let s = 'teste 123 outro teste fim';
let antiga = 'teste';
let nova = 'abcde';

s = s.replace(new RegExp(antiga + '(?!.*' + antiga + '.*$)(.*?)$'), nova + '$1');
console.log(s);
// teste 123 outro abcde fim
```

No caso, a regex criada é equivalente a `teste(?!.*teste.*$)(.*?)$` (ou seja, a string `teste`, desde que não tenha nenhuma outra ocorrência de "teste" até o final da string). Em seguida, eu continuo capturando o restante da string até o fim, para poder ter a varíavel `$1` e usá-la no `replace`.

Comment: muito obrigado gente, a regex deu certo, e também utilizando a substring e o lastIndexOf também funcionou, abriu muito minha mente, valeu demais

Comment: @iagomiranda Se uma das respostas resolveu o seu problema, vc pode escolher a que melhor resolveu e aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.